# Shiny renderPlot using action button

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to create a Shiny app where the user can select the x and y axes to plot, then click "Add Graph" for the graph to plot - but this code isn't working and I'm unsure why. Do I need to set `input$x_iris` and `input$y_iris` as reactives?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("4 Plot Generator"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(6, selectInput("x_iris", "X:", choices= c(unique(colnames(iris))))),
        column(6, selectInput("y_iris", "Y:", choices = c(unique(colnames(iris)))))
      ),

      # button to add graph
      # button to remove graph
      fluidRow(
        column(6, actionButton("add_graph", "Add Graph")),
        column(6, actionButton("reset_graph", "Reset Graphs"))
      )

    ),

    # Show graph
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plots")
    )
    )
  )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$add_graph,{
    # not sure why this isn't working
    plot1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = input$x_iris, y = input$y_iris)) + geom_point()
    output$plots <- renderPlot({
      plot1
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset_graph,{
    plot1 <- NULL
    output$plots <- renderPlot({
      plot1
    })
  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `selectInput` widgets are returning `character` values and `aes()` doesn't expect that. So to tell it to evaluate the input values properly, you use the combination of `aes_()` and `as.name()`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes_(x = as.name(input$x_iris), y = as.name(input$y_iris)))
```